# Low light when using Macro Reversing Ring

Tags: lens, nikon, macro, nikon-d5100

I just purchased `Macro Reversing Ring` for my `Nikon d5100(18-55lens)`, but I observed that whenevever I try to use it I am getting very dark images, They are so dark that I cannot capture them without artificial light source, doesn't matter I increase ISO, exposure etc.

Is this a normal thing when using Macro Reversing Ring ? or am I doing something wrong ?

Please guide me to capture Macros using Macro Reversing Ring

Comment: I wrote a blog post for Photo SE, way back, that explains in detail how to use a reversing ring, including overcoming the problem you're having. Check it out: http://photo.blogoverflow.com/2011/07/take-macro-shots-like-this-for-less-than-the-cost-of-a-pizza/

Comment: Okay ! so moral of the story is, I need to check whether my 18-55mm lens have manual aperture control botton, Let me check it

Comment: not so much a 'manual control button' as the ability to manually actuate the little metal lever on the lens, but yes

Comment: ElendilTheTall, Thanks a lot for giving idea about that lever, It worked

Comment: You sound surprised! ;) Happy snapping.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that with a reverse macro adapter, the lens loses all electrical connection with the camera and thus its aperture will stay in the default setting, which is usually the smallest possible aperture that gives you very little light.

If the lens does not have manual aperture control, I heard that you can get an "aperture control attachment", not sure if this is available for all lenses though.

Note that if you do manage to open your aperture, you'll notice that you now have a different problem: depth of field will be very, *very* limited, making it hard to get pictures where the parts you want to show are in focus.

Macro photography is difficult!

Comment: You don't need an adaptor. Providing your lens has an external aperture lever (most Nikon-compatible lenses do) you can just hold it open.

Comment: As an aside, default on Nikon lenses is narrowest aperture. Other manufacturers differ. Canon lenses are wide open by default, but will hold whatever aperture they are physically at when removed from a camera, so you could set f/5.6, push and hold the DoF preview button while you remove the lens and it will stay at f/5.6 until it is reattached electrically to a camera that is turned on. No guessing on what aperture the lens is at by manually pushing a mechanical linkage because the diaphragm is moved by an electrical servo inside the lens!

Comment: Found a lever on nikon 18-55 lens, thanks for answer